# What should be default value for SortExpression Google App Engine search for 'distance()'?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

I have such SortExpression:

```
from google.appengine.api.search import search

search.SortExpression(expression = 'distance(geoLocation, geopoint(%s, %s))' 
                      % (geoLatitude, geoLongitude),
                      direction = search.SortExpression.ASCENDING,
                      default_value = sys.float_info.max)
```

**What should be `default_value` for `distance()`?**

Currently `sys.float_info.max` works on SDK but generates errors on production:

```
InvalidRequest: Failed to parse search request "tag:"zamówienia internetowe" AND tag:"zamówienia na teraz""; Default text value is not appropriate for sort expression 'distance(geoLocation, geopoint(52.1967225, 20.8892005))'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the default to be last in the results, I'd suggest picking a value that's larger than half the circumference of the Earth at its widest point (i.e., the equator). I believe that any value greater than 20,038,000 meters should be larger than any possible distance, even accounting for future refinements in how we model the Earth in production.

Chris

Comment: The problem is related to unicode letter typical for Polish language = English letters + ąćęłóńśżźż - qx. I was miss that it is not problem of distance because unicode works on SDK.